# How to increase the maximum file size when using Ghost docker image and Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ghost-blog

I am hosting a Ghost blog using Kubernetes and the docker image ghost with version 3.16.1. While uploading a theme, I get a error message that the file size is to large.

> The file you uploaded was larger than the maximum file size your server allows.

I have been remoting into the pod to see if I found any settings there that I could configure without see any. Can not see what configuration to add in the deployment file to increase the default.

I have a Ingress controller that is using Nginx and is specifying "nginx.org/client-max-body-size", but that did not help after I added that one.

Do anyone know how I can increase the maximum file size while using the Ghost docker image and nginx ingress controller? Below is part of the ingress conroller configuation file and the deployment file.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: beitostolenlive-no-ingress
  namespace: beitostolenlive-no
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: "30s"
    nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: "20s"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "50m"
```

Here is the deployment configuration file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: beitostolenlive-no
    namespace: beitostolenlive-no
    labels:
        web: beitostolenlive-no
spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy:
        type: Recreate
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            web: beitostolenlive-no
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                web: beitostolenlive-no
        spec:
            containers:
            - name: beitostolenlive-no
              image: ghost:3.16.1
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              ports:
                - containerPort: 2368
              env:
                - name: url
                  value: https://beitostolenlive.no
                - name: database__client
                  value: mysql
                - name: database__connection__host
                  value: ***
                - name: database__connection__user
                  value: ***
                - name: database__connection__password
                  value: ***
                - name: database__connection__database
                  value: ***
              volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /var/lib/ghost/content
                name: content
            volumes:
            - name: content
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: beitostolenlive-no-content
```

Comment: Did you try to add nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size annotation ?

Comment: So I ll post it as solution that you can accept and be more visible for other community ?

Comment: Yeah, if you post that solution, I will mark it as accepted. @MaggieO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size` annotation to your ingress configuration file.

For NGINX, an such error will be returned to the client when the size in a request exceeds the maximum allowed size of the client request body. This size can be configured by the parameter  [`client_max_body_size`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size).

To configure this setting globally for all Ingress rules, the  `proxy-body-size`  value may be set in the  [NGINX ConfigMap](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap.md#proxy-body-size). To use custom values in an Ingress rule define annotation I have mentioned.

Useful information: [custom-max-body-size](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#custom-max-body-size), [413-k8s-helm](https://jessicadeen.com/error413-k8s-helm/).